# Sorting Algorithm - Bubble Sort

Tags: bubble-sort

I was trying to understand bubble sort. While implementing my own version of it for practicing, I implemented it in such a way:

```
public int[] sort(int[] nums) {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.println(++x);
                if (nums[j] > nums[i]) {
                    int temp = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[i];
                    nums[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Notice how the inner loop goes from 0 to i.

When I googled this algorithm to find the conventional implementation, I found this implementation:

```
public int[] sortnew(int[] nums) {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length - i - 1; j++) {
                System.out.println(++x);
                if (nums[j] > nums[j+1]) {
                    int temp = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[j+1];
                    nums[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Here i goes from 0 to array length - i - 1.

In both the cases the number of prints of 'x' are the same. This I believe indicates that the number of computations are same. Then what exactly is the difference between the two practically? 
Thank you!

Comment: Your own attempt looks like [exchange sort](https://www.codingunit.com/exchange-sort-algorithm), except that the loops should be `(int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)` and `(int j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++)`. Right now, the first iteration of your outer loop is pointless since `j < i` obviously is false when `i` and `j` both are 0.

Comment: Thank you! That link explains it